# Calling a method when the user login Django

Tags: django

On my Django site, I want to create an object when the user login the site. I searched it on the internet and I decided to write a method in a context_processors.py. so I wrote;

```
def check_online_status(request):
   user_status = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_status = UserStatus.objects.create(user_id=request.user.id)
        user_status.status_type = "online"
        user_status.save()

return {
    'user_status': user_status,
}
```

Here it is the problem; my check_online_status() method is triggered in every request but I want to trigger my method at once, only when the user login.

Can you help me to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a signal, specifically an auth signal. These are already provided in django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in


  def set_status_online(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
      user_status = UserStatus.objects.create(user_id=request.user.id)
      user_status.status_type = "online"
      user_status.save()

  user_logged_in.connect(set_status_online)
```